# Run shared service when other service exits with sucess

Tags: systemd

I'm looking for a way to share a service between two other services without making the "other" two services dependent of each other:

```
a.service (oneshot) 
b.service (oneshot)
```

`shared.service` (oneshot, and runs with different user/capabilities then service `a` and `b`)

I want the `shared.service` to run if `a.service` OR `b.service` exits with success. In the shared.service file I tried with `Requires=a.service b.service` but then `a` and `b` become dependent of each other.

Only way that I can think of is to split the shared.service into two but I thought a shared would be prettier.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should put `Wants=shared.service` (or `Requires=shared.service`) and `Before=shared.service` in a.service and b.service.

Comment: Tried that but shared.service always get called when service a or b returns with exitcode 1

Comment: @LarsP thanks, that clarifies it for me. If the shared unit is small it might be simplest to split it. But you could perhaps try `ExecStartPost=/bin/systemctl start shared.service`.

Comment: If I do the ExecStartPost it will run with the same capabilities as a.service or b.service. I thought it would be best practice to do one job per service and lock them down with only needed capabilities.

Comment: @LarsP by running `systemctl start shared.service`, it should start `shared.service` correctly, according to the capabilities defined in `shared.service`.